# Struggling to solve an integral related to sigmoid functions wrapped on a circle

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve the following integral

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(x)\exp{(-\sin(x-\alpha))}\cos(x-\alpha)}{(1 + \exp(-\sin(x-\alpha)))^2}dx$

By parts I end up with the following result (seperated into two terms)

$\left[\frac{\sin(x)}{1 + \exp(-\sin(x-\alpha))}\right]^{\pi}_{-\pi}$

which is the first time and evalautes to $0$, and then the second term

$ - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{1 + \exp(-\sin(x-\alpha))}dx$

which I do not know how to solve.

Any assistance on solving this integral would be very helpful.  Thank you!